# Getting data from database using part of the URL as a value - PHP

Tags: mysql, database-connection

My url type is like "http://localhost/boardgame/profile/Duncan/" the last word is the user name...

I just try to get some data from database and I need a user name to do this. I tried to get it from page URL but it doesn't work. Where did I go wrong? What has to be done? I'll be greateful if anybody can help...

```php
<?php


$actual_link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

//echo $actual_link;

$rest = substr($actual_link, 35, -1);  

echo $rest;

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bgt");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

    die ("Veritabanı bağlantısında hata var");

} if (($rest) !="") {

    if (get_current_user_id($link) == '0') {

        echo "<p>Kullanıcının koleksiyonunu görebilmek için giriş yapmanız 
    gerekiyor.</p>";

          } else {

        $query = "SELECT TITLE FROM wp_user_collections WHERE `user_name` = 
   '".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $rest)."'";

        echo "<div><h1>'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $rest)."'in 
Koleksiyonu</h1><div>";

        if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)){

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

        echo "<table>";

        echo "<tr>";                
            echo "<th>Oyun Adı</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>'" . $row['TITLE'] . "'</td>";
        echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo "</table></div>";
      }  
    }           
  }

} else {

echo "Kullanıcının koleksiyonunu görebilmek için <a 
href='http://localhost/boardgame/profile/'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$rest)."'>tıklayınız</a>";
}

?>
```

Comment: If the username is given in the URL, what is all that PHP code about?

Comment: To get some data from database about that user...

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Reading the username from the URL or writing the proper query to get the data from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I have thought...using array then extracting the last element (or second last since there is a trailing '/' slash which is a delimiter)

```
$uri="http://localhost/boardgame/profile/Duncan/";
$uriParts=explode('/', $uri);             //converts the uri string into an array of words separated by forward slash
$name=$uriParts[sizeOf($uriParts)-1-1];   //the user name comes from 2nd last item as the last item is empty
echo $name;
```

I could suggest you use Regular Expression to extract the user name, however I'm not well versed with it yet.

Comment: Thanks for the advice and thank you for  a quick response, but that didn't work either, is there any problem with my "query"?

Comment: What errors are you getting exactly? Could be a problem with your queries.

Comment: No errors, just can't see the array list on the page.

Comment: Just solved it, found out that, when data gets in the database, it collects user names with a quote, that's why I can't get the right database object when I tried to recall it... Thanks everyone, case is closed... – Selch 28 mins ago